# Possible to fail maven build when any PIT mutation fails, rather than mutation coverage?

Tags: java, maven, pitest

I'm using the pitest-maven plugin for my project, and would like to have the maven build fail if there is any mutation that fails.

But I can't see a configuration option that allows me to do that. I can see **mutationThreshold** and **coverageThreshold**, but neither of those work.

Ideally, I'd like to use PIT to make sure the tests I've written don't fail any mutations, rather than try to meet a blanket coverage metric.

Is there any way to do that?

Current maven configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mutationThreshold>100</mutationThreshold>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of pitest (I think 1.6.2+) include a test strength threshold, which only considers code that is covered (i.e., you'd need to add an additional coverage limit if the build should fail for uncovered lines).

```
   /**
   * Test strength score threshold at which to fail build
   */
  @Parameter(defaultValue = "0", property = "testStrengthThreshold")
  private int                         testStrengthThreshold;
```

Related:

- https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/issues/128
- https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/pull/774

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting so much later! Not currently working on anything using PIT at the moment, but I'll definitely give this a go when I've got some time. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want PIT to fail anytime a mutated test doesn't fail you should only have to set `mutationThreshold` to `100` meaning complete coverage for all mutations generated.

Comment: That was my first step, but once I solved all mutations (from the report output) l, the build still failed since the mutation coverage was below 100, as the unit test coverage was low.

Comment: You can leave the `coverageThreshold` out if you dont need it.

Comment: I've updated the OP with my maven configuration, I've not been using coverage threshold. I checked the report for my package, and none of the mutations are failing, but the build fails as the total "score" is less than 100.